# Why is this public member function "undefined"? (C++)

Tags: c++

I am a student just starting learning C++ classes.

In the snippet below, why can't I access the public member function "difference" from main() and pass in account1 and account2? Error says that difference is undefined.

```
class BankAccount 
    {
    public:
        double difference(BankAccount account1, BankAccount account2);
    private:
        double balance;
        double interest_rate;

        double fraction(double percent);
    };
    int main()
    {
        BankAccount account1, account2;

        account1.set(100, 5.0);
        account2.set(203,4.0);
        difference(account1, account2);

        return 0;
    }
    void BankAccount::set(int dollars, double rate)
    {
        if((dollars < 0)||(rate < 0))
        {
            cout << "Illegal values for money or interest rate.\n";
            exit(1);
        }
        balance = dollars;
        interest_rate = rate;
    }
    double BankAccount::difference(BankAccount account1, BankAccount account2)
    {
        return account1.balance - account2.balance;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function is a non-static member function so you cannot call like this

```
difference(account1, account2);
```

You must call it on an instance of the class `BankAccount` like you did previously here

```
account1.set(100, 5.0);
```

Calling it in the way you have will only work for a stand alone function, *not* a member function.

Comment: Thank you. That seemed odd to me since I am sending account1 and account2 to the function. Using account1.difference(account1, account2) works.

Comment: If you provided an accessor function for the member `balance` you could actually define the function as a non-member function. It looks like the only reason you need it as a member function is to get access to the private data member.

Comment: Thank you. I do have an accessor function for getting the balance, just didn't paste it in for this question. That is a great point. I will rethink my implementation.